# Generate Geometric random graphs in r

Tags: r, graph-theory

I have a graph containing 16809 nodes an 173,393 edges. Now i want to generate a geometric random graph with same number of nodes and edges in r. How can  I achieve that.

My example R script is as follows.

```
library(igraph)
g2 <- graph.formula(A:B - A:C, B:D - C:D , D:F - D:F )
g2
```

Then how can I model g2 in geometric random graph. Is there any function to create this random graphs in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function to generate GRG by known radius and number of nodes, see `sample_grg`. But the concept of GRGs means that nodes are placed randomly, so the number of edges will be random. The following code gives pretty close results to what you need:

```
g <- sample_grg(16809, 0.02)
```

But I don't think there is a way to somehow determine the number of edges.

Comment: @domin Can't we add edges by specifying the number..??

Comment: @jaspsingh What number are you talking about? The number of edges is random every time. Surely you can modify the graph afterwards by adding new connections, but will it then be geometric **random** graph? I'm not sure.